# DefaultRoot in proftpd.conf does not work properly

Tags: linux, proftpd

I have configuration of proftpd like this:

```
DefaultRoot ~ User
```

I try to jail User to home directory but this does not work so i try this:

```
DefaultRoot /home/userfolder ftp-proftpd
```

This should jail everybody who is in ftp-proftpd group into userfolder directory. But this did not work neither. I can connect over ftp client but I am in "/" directory and cannot open any of the folder. Can anybodey explain me how this work? I try configure proftpd according to proftpd documentation. I expected that after this configuration directive i will be in home direcotry or in userfolder directory after login to ftp server.

Comment: The [`DefaultRoot`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Chroot.html) syntax uses an optional _group_ name, *not* _user_ name (as implied by your first example).  Also, what FTP client are you using to test?  What does the server side [debug logging](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Debugging.html) show, when you try to list the directory?